# Retirar 1 dia de uma data específica

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Gostaria de uma ajuda no banco de dados, onde eu pego uma data e depois que eu pegar essa data eu preciso retirar 1 dia dela, assim puxando o resultado de 1 dia anterior a data informada.
Como eu poderia fazer isso?

EXEMPLO -> `AND ped_data BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-03-31 23:59:59'`

Eu preciso retirar o dia na segunda data informada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poderia utilizar a função `DATEADD` se você estiver utilizando SQL.

```sql
AND ped_data BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND DATEADD(dd, -1, '2020-03-31 23:59:59')
```

Onde `dd` significa Dia, e `-1` significa que você vai subtrair 1.

Ou se você estiver utilizando MySQL, você pode utilizar a função `ADDDATE`.

```sql
AND ped_data BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND ADDDATE('2020-03-31 23:59:59', INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

Onde `-1` significa que você vai subtrair 1, e `DAY` significa que será alterado o dia.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá ThRnk, como eu estou usando no PostgreSql eu usei o "INTERVAL - 1 DAY" e deu super certo, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda e pela paciência, que você cresça bastante profissionalmente, forte abraços.

Answer (score 3):

Dependendo qual servidor que você está usando tem uma função para adicionar/subtrair datas.

**MYSQL**

```
DATE_ADD("2017-06-15", INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

**SQL Server**

```
DATEADD (day, -1, "2017-06-15")
```

**PostgreSQL**

```
DATE '2017-06-15' - INTERVAL '1 day'
```

Comment: Olá pessoal, muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu super certo utilizando o "INTERVAL", agora sei como aplicar ele quando tiver que solucionar problemas como esses, agradeço fortemente pela ajuda e pela paciência, tudo de bom para vocês sempre